# js_of_ocaml Camlp4 Parse error in type definition

Tags: ocaml, camlp4, js-of-ocaml

I'm trying to build [this program](https://github.com/ott-lang/ott) using js_of_ocaml. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383500/how-to-use-modules-with-js-of-ocaml), I've got the following line in my makefile

```
OCAMLC      = ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml -package js_of_ocaml.syntax -syntax camlp4o -linkpkg -g -dtypes
```

However, when I try to build, I get the following error:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml -package js_of_ocaml.syntax -syntax camlp4o -linkpkg -g -dtypes   -c types.ml
> File "types.ml", line 472, characters 11-12:
> Parse error: [type_longident] expected after ")" (in [type_ident_and_parameters])
> File "types.ml", line 1:
```

The offending line of the file is this:

```
type ('t,'v) parser = ('t list -> 'v -> unit) -> 't list -> unit
```

I'm still pretty new to OCaml, so I'm not totally sure what's going on.
What does the `-syntax camlp4o` do? What kinds of things in the source might I need to change to be compatible with js_of_ocaml?

Comment: `parser` is a special keyword for `camlp4o`, while it is not in the vanilla OCaml.  You have to rename it as far as you want to use it.

Comment: Exactly the problem. Write it as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`camlp4o` provides the same syntax as the vanilla OCaml syntax, but with slight incompatibility: `parser` is a special keyword in `camlp4o`.  This is why `parser` is rejected if you use `camlp4o` syntax.

You can workaround this problem by renaming `parser`, or using PPX syntax extension of `js_of_ocaml` instead of CamlP4.  Please check https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/api/Ppx_js for details of this newer syntax helper for `js_of_ocaml`.

Comment: What arguments do I give to ocamlfind to use PPX? I couldn't find one on the Ocsigen page. The examples all seem to use PPX, but the example ocamlc call uses camlp4o

Comment: `ocamlfind ocamlc ... -package js_of_ocaml.ppx`